# I just want to leave this off-topic question here

Tags: discussion

I just got back from work.
I have to do some cleaning in the house, then watch something to relax in order to go to sleep for the iteration of the next day.

So, why this question was off-topic I leave it to you, because I honestly don't have time to bother.
-Is SuperUser a better place now that the question was closed?
-What terrible thing would have happened if the question remained open?
-Should the comments where I explained the reason why I thought that was a legit question be preserved? Or other peoples comments?

The Question:
[Which Routers have good long-term updates?](https://superuser.com/questions/1739623/which-routers-have-good-long-term-updates)

Have a nice day :-)

Comment: I am confused by your complaint. You literally got the answer you were looking for, what’s so bad about closing questions, that were have determined are better suited for other SE communities? Your question was specifically looking for a hardware recommendation, this wasn’t the case of a poorly worded question, you literally asked for a suggestion.

Comment: Link is dead. Long live the link

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to leave this off-topic question here

It's possible you've chosen some unfortunate wording here for the title.

The way this reads is, *"My question was off-topic, but I want to leave it here on Super User anyway."*

When I *think* you mean something like:

*"I have a question about why my post was considered off-topic that I want to ask here (on Meta)"*

Reasonable questions about why a question is off-topic are absolutely welcome on Super User, so hopefully you really mean the latter.

> why this question was off-topic I leave it to you, because I honestly don't have time to bother

I guess I'm confused on this part of your question, as that seems to have been very clearly explained in both the comments as well as the banner at the top of the Close reason.

There's even a handy link in the Close banner to the Stack Exchange Co-founder's blog from 2010 [explaining *exactly why*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) the decision was made to not allow Shopping Recommendations 12 years ago.

Again here, perhaps you've just chosen poor wording.  I'm sure you can't really be saying that you don't have the time to read the explanations that have already been provided, but you have time to post this Meta question, right?!

Why *part* of the explanations that have been given don't you understand?

> Is Super User a better place now that the question was closed?

Yes!  Absolutely!  While things are sometimes closed here that I don't think should be, yours was absolutely an off-topic question.  And keeping the questions on this site on-topic is certainly something that makes Super User better, IMHO.  As the linked blog explains, answers to your question would constantly be changing over time.  So what's highly upvoted or accepted today is *very likely* absolutely wrong in the future.  Having a hardware recommendation stay here, where it isn't allowed, would absolutely degrade *purpose* of the site.

> What terrible thing would have happened if the question remained open?

- Answers becoming out-of-date.  Users finding those out-of-date recommendations through a web search at some point in the future and having no idea how relevant they are today.
- Dozens of competing and conflicting answers over time detailing other users' experiences with updates (or lack thereof) on certain manufacturer's firmwares.
- An increase in necessary moderation due to similar answers or "me too" not-an-answers.
- A breakdown of the Q&A structure that Super User tries to follow into a "discussion" like Reddit.

> Should the comments where I explained the reason why I thought that was a legit question be preserved? Or other peoples comments?

Comments *are* typically preserved unless things start getting out-of-hand or violate a rule.  But the proper way to make your case as for why the question is on-topic is really here on Meta.  But I don't see that you've done that here.  There's no reasoning given in your question *here* as to why you think your question isn't a recommendation for hardware.